# Convert latitude and longitude to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df like these
3 first rows are these

| City | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toluca | W099.6569 | N19.2925 |
| Pune | E73.8562 | N18.5167 |
| Bloemfontain | E026.216667 | S29.116667 |

For example Bloemfontain row should be like these at the end

| City | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bloemfontain | -29.116667 | 26.216667 |

I used this code

```
pattern = r'(?P<d>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<m>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<s>[\d\.]+)'
dms = df['Latitude'].str.extract(pattern).astype(float)
df['LATITUDE'] = dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600)
dms = df['Longitude'].str.extract(pattern).astype(float)
df['LONGITUDE'] = dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600)
```

but got not the right longitude and latitude

Comment: What type of object is latitude and longitude? Can you do this and tell me what it prints: `print(type(df['Latitude']))`. Is it a string?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: ok now try printing this: `type(df['Latitude'].str)`

Comment: pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods

Comment: Your `pattern` seems to be expecting the geographic coordinates in degrees, minutes and seconds but such inputs are not indicated anywhere in your question.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know which pattern should I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where it is necessary to utilize a pattern search at all.  Here is how I would do the task.

```
# function to perform the partitioning
def cnvrtCoord(val: str) -> float:
    sgn = +1
    if val[0] == 'S' or val[0] == 'W':
        sgn = -1
    return float(val[1:]) * sgn
```

Then to change the contents of the Longitude and Latitude columns use:

```
df['Longitude'] = [cnvrtCoord(x) for x in df['Longitude'].tolist()]
df['Latitude'] = [cnvrtCoord(x) for x in df['Latitude'].tolist()]
```

This would produce the dataframe shown below given your input sample:

```
    City    Longitude   Latitude
0   Toluca  -99.656900  19.292500
1   Pune    73.856200   18.516700
2   Bloemfontain    26.216667   -29.116667
```